# Unable to install Symfony

Tags: symfony, xampp, frameworks, windows-7

I'm following the official Symfony installation instructions but it doesn't work.

If i download and run the setup.exe I get an error status "Failed to send request to HTTP server" error and i can't proceed with installation. If I download binaries for windows(symfony_windows_amd64.exe) it doesn't work either.

I can run "composer create-project symfony/skeletonS my_project_name" but I don't have access to Symfony console commands -  "*bash: symfony:: command not found
"*.

Setup: Xampp, win7.

Comment: Please help us identify the issue. Do you get an error message when you install the symfony command line tool, e.g. symfony_windows_amd64.exe, or is the command just not available afterwards (like you describe for bash)? Which command line are you using (Windows Command Line, PowerShell or a different one, e.g. Cygwin)?

Comment: I'm using windows command line or git bash - there is no difference. The "Failed to send request to HTTP server" comes while executing setup.exe(inside the setup) from symfony.com/downloads and i can't proceed with installation.                                      The is another file in downloads -  binary setup file "symfony_windows_amd64.exe" If ran it quickly opens and closes command line and it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I don't have Windows, so I can't check if it is a server issue, but I doubt it. Most likely it's a local issue, e.g. firewall settings or a missing library like openssl. Unfortunately without additional error output, it's hard to tell. Have you checked the issue tracker at https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues?

Comment: As far as I can tell the binaries should work. Can you check your environment variables for PATH and see if the folder where you keep the binary is in the list?

Comment: I'm completely novice in this i'm not sure what you mean. How do I do it ?

Comment: C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm  - that's my path variable value in system settings.

Comment: In your search bar type "environment variables" and it should give you 2 options (system environment variables or user environment variables). On your home computer either should be fine, but I suggest the user-specific ones. There you have a list of variables, one of them is PATH. When you double click you see a list of paths that you can sort or add new ones, e.g. your Download directory. Afterwards in your bash (after closing and opening a new window) when you type the command it should be found.

Comment: Yes, those paths look right. You can either copy the binary in one of those directories or add a new one.

Comment: my C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Composer doesnt't have vendor\bin directory. Should i reinstall composer ? the C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Composer folder have: .htaccess; 4old.phar files; keys.dev.pub; keys.tags.pub, update-channel

Comment: Just so you know what you are changing there: The PATH is where your system will look for executables when you type in a command and it can not find it in the current directory. It will go through the list from top to bottom and the first command in one of those places that matches will be used. This way in your command line no matter which folder you are in you can execute the symfony-command (without specifying the exact location).

Comment: "Should i reinstall composer ?" No, not necessary. You can install composer packages globally with `composer global require phpunit/phpunit`. It will install it there instead of in your project. You can then use this global phpunit to run tests without installing it in each project. Sometimes that is helpful when composer will not install tools in your project, because of dependency conflicts.

Comment: I put in "symfony_windows_amd64.exe"(from symfony.com/downloads 64bit binary) in "C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Composer" executed it but nothing appeared and happened :/

Comment: Do you know if "symfony_windows_amd64.exe" is the installer or the actual cli command? Can you execute it in your cli with this name, not just "symfony"?

Comment: The .htaccess text is "Deny from all"

Comment: If it really doesn't work, but running "composer create-project" works. You can call the commands on windows directly in your project without using Symfony CLI by running the following command (when you are in your project directory): `php bin/console list`

Comment: It's from the download page "If you prefer, you can download the binaries directly from GitHub: 32-bit or 64-bit platforms." it's an .exe file  I'm not sure what it is. whats the command to execute it ?

Comment: Yes the "php/bin console" command works but it doesn't have server:start, server:stop and other commands that I will need following the tutorial, thats the problem. I manage to find how to start a server by other means("php -S localhost8000 -t public") but i believe I will ran into another problems by not having that symfony commands later on. Anyways thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give us the location where symfony cli binary has been installed and the output of `echo $PATH`.